# Encrypting a file using a private key and public key

Tags: ssl, encryption

I am a developer with very little experience of encryption.  I am trying to learn more about Encryption and specifically SSL in my spare time.

Say a trusted company has a file (notepad) that contains a load of personal and confidential information.  Say I wanted to ask them to send this information to a me to analyze.  How would I do this?

My research is telling me that I would have to:

1) Create a self signed certificate
2) Generate the public and private key
3) Issue the public key to the trusted company and keep the private key
4) Ask the company to encrypt the information using the public key and then send it to me
5) Decrypt the file using the private key

Is that correct? How would I do this?

Should the certificate be signed by a Certificate Authority in this case as I would manually be issuing the public key to the trusted company (they know it comes from me).

As I said I am relatively new to this subject.

Comment: SSL/TLS is not used to encrypt files. It is used to establish encrypted connections. If you really want to encrypt files for storage, then you can't do this with SSL/TLS. It seems you just simply mean public-key-encryption. If so, then yes, that is a way to do it.

Comment: Note that the size of the data you can encrypt with RSA is limited to less than the key size. Since the reference is to  SSL note that the data is encrypted with a symmetric key such as AES and that key is encrypted with asymmetric encryption such as RSA. This is sometimes called hybrid encryption.

Comment: @Zaph, thanks for your comment.  However, I do not want to be an "expert".  I am just trying to grasp the basics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSL is a protocol for encrypting network connections.  It's not really relevant for manually encrypting and decrypting files.  (It's also insecure and deprecated; TLS should be used instead.)

If you want to manually encrypt and decrypt files, yes, you could use a self-signed certificate and just give the public key to the company that'll send the file.  However, you have to make sure to give them the public key in a way that can't be intercepted — such as physically handing it over on a flash drive, *not* emailing it — or you're vulnerable to a [man-in-the-middle attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack): someone could intercept the public key and give the company a *different* one instead.  (If that happened, the company would unknowingly be encrypting the file for the attacker to decrypt, and the attacker would then re-encrypt the file with the *real* public key and send it along to you.)

If you're doing this manually and you deliver the public key in a secure way, you don't need to involve a certificate authority.  The purpose of a certificate authority is to vouch for the authenticity of a certificate when it's delivered over an insecure channel.  For example, when you visit stackoverflow.com, your browser gets a certificate (with a public key) from the web server.  Since this certificate wasn't personally given to you by SO staff, how do you know that the web server is the real stackoverflow.com, not a man-in-the-middle attacker intercepting your connection in order to hijack your account?  The website's certificate is signed by a certificate authority — DigiCert, currently — that says DigiCert has verified that it's real.  Your browser is configured to trust that signature from DigiCert, because the browser developers have verified that the company is trustworthy.

[PGP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pretty_Good_Privacy) and [GPG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Privacy_Guard) are good tools for securely exchanging encrypted files.  They use a "web-of-trust" model based on securely exchanging certificates, rather than relying on a certificate authority.